# What is this fallacy called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to show that $\frac{1}{x} \neq 0$ by contradiction:

$$\begin{align} \frac{1}{x} &= 0\ \text{(multiplty by $x$)} \\[6pt]
1 &= 0\end{align}$$

*Btw I know other ways to prove this (i.e. proving this is not the goal of my question)*

Someone pointed out that you cannot time by $x$. I know why one cannot divide by $x$.

Say $x +1 = 2$. If I times by $x$, I get $x^2 -x = 0$ which leads to the solutions $x = 0,-1$. Obviously $x=0$ is extraneous and can be ruled out, also, this step was unnecessary but this isn't fallacious though- or is it?

Comment: Whay you proved is simply that $1/x \neq 0$. Good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct. It is **always** the case that
$$a=b$$
implies
$$f(a)=f(b)$$
for any function $f$ applied to both sides. In particular,
$$\frac{1}x=0$$
implies
$$1=0$$
since we can take $f$ to be "multiply by $x$" - which is a perfectly good function, even if $x$ were zero (note that the same cannot be said of "divide by $x$"). Of course, $1\neq 0$, so this is a contradiction and thus it cannot be that $\frac{1}x=0$ for any $x$ since that implies a contradiction. (Or, perhaps more precisely we might say that if $y\cdot x=1$ then $y\neq 0$, in order to avoid possibly writing $\frac{1}0$ by accident)

The danger of multiplying by $x$ is that the statements $a=b$ and $f(a)=f(b)$ might not be *equivalent* - which allows for extra solutions to sneak in. In your example, if you start with
$$x-1=0$$
then multiplying by $x$ gives
$$x^2-x=0.$$
It's certainly true that if $x-1=0$ then $x^2-x=0$. The extraneous solution comes from the fact that $x^2-x=0$ doesn't imply that $x-1=0$ - but your argument isn't trying to use this reverse direction, so it's not an issue that extraneous solutions might pop in.

This is a point that sometimes gets overlooked, since algebra is most often done using functions such as "add $2$" or "subtract $x$" which are invertible (or at least "injective"), which allows us to prove the reverse implication - formally, if for the functions $f$, there's another $g$ so that $g(f(x))=x$, we can find that $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$ which then implies $a=b$ - meaning that then $a=b$ and $f(a)=f(b)$ are equivalent. Working with functions that aren't like this - such as squaring both sides or multiplying by some $x$ that might be zero - feels different, but as long as you keep track of the direction of the implication, there is absolutely no problem in doing so.

Comment: This is specious reasoning about definitions that over-simplifies the logical problems about dealing with "undefined" terms: you are assuming that you can can apply the law $x\cdot\frac{1}{x} = 1$ even when $x = 0$.. It is standard (and usually necessary) in model theory to define $\frac{1}{0}$ to have a definite value (usually $0$).

Comment: @RobArthan While there's surely something to be said of exactly what is meant by $\frac{1}x$, it feels like that point is less salient to the question than whether "multiply by $x$" is an okay step in general. As long as we interpret $\frac{1}x$ to mean "any $y$ so that $y\cdot x=1$" (as I briefly note in the answer), the OP's proof is okay - and I think that's a reasonable interpretation in this context, especially as the question explicitly asks about this aspect and not about dealing with undefined terms.